# Chef Error - stopping a service, deleting a file relate to that service

Tags: chef-infra, upstart

I am trying to write an upstart script to manage the New Relic system monitoring plugin (which by default uses an init.d script).

I do not want this because if the newrelic-sysmond daemon fails, then I will have to restart the service manually, which is not ideal. Also, i prefer upstart in general.

Here are my two resources that handle this from my recipe.

```
file "/etc/init.d/newrelic-sysmond" do
  action :nothing
end

service "newrelic-sysmond" do
  supports :status => true, :start => true, :stop => true, :restart => true
  action :stop
  notifies :delete, 'file[/etc/init.d/newrelic-sysmond]', :immediately
end
```

Now, when I run this recipe I get a strange Error, telling me that the service newrelic-sysmond cannot restart because `/etc/init.d/newrelic-sysmond` does not exist?

So my question is, why is chef trying to restart the service after I've told it stop. And also, I would expect the `service "newrelic-sysmond"` to complete and notify the file resource to then complete the deletion of `/etc/init.d/newrelic-sysmond`

Any thoughts? Thank-you.

Answer (score 1):

Three things. The first two are just to clean up your code a bit, the third should fix you problem.

First, `:start => true` and `:stop => true` are not relevant.  `supports` is only interested in `:restart`, `:status`, and `:reload`.

Second, you need a `not_if` on your `service` resource.  Otherwise you'll get an error the second time this cookbook runs when it tries to `:stop` the init.d service and can't find the file.

```
service 'newreslic-sysmond' do
  supports :status => true, :restart => true
  action :stop
  notifies :delete, 'file[/etc/init.d/newrelic-sysmod]', :delayed
end
```

Third, the cookbook that installs the newrelic-sysmond service is probably also notifying the resource to restart somewhere.  You can deal with that in several, listed from prettiest to ugliest.

## Prevent the service from ever being created

If you can figure out where that `service` resource is being created in the first place, you may be able to prevent it.  (We can help with that if you give us some more info)

## Don't remove the file until after the restart.

The downside is you'll start, stop, and delete the init.d script EVERY chef run, but you can do it. Simply make your notification to delete the file a `:delayed` notification.  So long as it is later on the delayed notification stack than your `restart`, you're golden.  This is somewhat fragile, as changes in your runlist could break it.

## Modify the notification stack

NOTE: this code is untested, but should be close, feel free to edit the response if I didn't get it quite right

```
ruby_block 'remove delayed restart on newrelic service' do
  block
    initd_resource = resources('service[newrelic-sysmond]')
    initd_notifications = initd_resource.delayed_notifications
    notification_collection = run_context.delayed_notification_collection
    initd_notifications.each{ |notif| notification_collection.delete(notif) }
  end
end
```

If you go this route, you may also want to modify the resource stack itself to ensure the `service` resource is never executed.  Otherwise you're still back to a case where each chef run could result in creating and removing again and again.  Also, the `resources` method will throw an error if the resource isn't found, so you may want to wrap it in some error control logic.